# Merge 2 collections, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join, merge

I have 2 collections and i want to merge them into 1 collection:

```
$campagnes3 = Leads1_Voorverzameld::select(array('leads1_voorverzameld.*', \DB::raw('COUNT(leads1_voorverzameld.Campagne_Id) as Avleads')))
    ->leftJoin('campagnes', 'campagnes.Campagne_Id', '=', 'leads1_voorverzameld.Campagne_Id')
    ->where('leads1_voorverzameld.Aanvullende_Gegevens', '=', '1')
    ->groupBy('leads1_voorverzameld.Campagne_Id', \DB::raw("YEAR(leads1_voorverzameld.Voorverzameld_Datum)"), \DB::raw("MONTH(leads1_voorverzameld.Voorverzameld_Datum)"))
    ->orderBy(\DB::raw("YEAR(leads1_voorverzameld.Voorverzameld_Datum)"))
    ->get();

    $campagnes4 = Leads1_Voorverzameld::select(array('leads1_voorverzameld.*', \DB::raw('COUNT(leads1_voorverzameld.Campagne_Id) as leads')))
    ->leftJoin('campagnes', 'campagnes.Campagne_Id', '=', 'leads1_voorverzameld.Campagne_Id')
    ->groupBy('leads1_voorverzameld.Campagne_Id', \DB::raw("YEAR(leads1_voorverzameld.Voorverzameld_Datum)"), \DB::raw("MONTH(leads1_voorverzameld.Voorverzameld_Datum)"))
    ->orderBy(\DB::raw("YEAR(leads1_voorverzameld.Voorverzameld_Datum)"))
    ->get();

$av = $campagnes3->toBase()->merge($campagnes4);
```

sending $av to my view

output now:

Gives me there are 2 voorverzamelde leads and then on next row there is 1 with AV and then voorverzamelde leads column is empty.

Output should be that there are 2 voorverzamelde Leads and 1 of them contains AV
so they should be linked. Any Help?

Comment: why don't you do a union in your raw sql?

Answer (score 0):

```
$av = $campagnes3->combine($campagnes4);
```

You can use the `combine` method from Laravel's collections.

It will merge your two collections into one if they have same attributes.